# What am I generating when I generate a java Calendar object?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, java.util.calendar

I am wondering how I should be using java Calendar objects in order to use them properly (use of this class is mandatory for my assignment so while I'd love to use some of the better options - they aren't options).

I've read the documentation here: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#:~:text=A%20Calendar%20object%20can%20produce,as%20well%20as%20their%20meaning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#:%7E:text=A%20Calendar%20object%20can%20produce,as%20well%20as%20their%20meaning).

And I still don't understand how to use a calendar object correctly.

I need to represent arrival and departure times for several train stations.  Should I use a separate Calendar object for each arrival time and departure time separately?  Can I include both in the same object?

What does a single Calendar object represent?  Is it a single point in time (ie Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute)?  Right now I'm using separate objects for each station's arrival and departure times.  That means I have a large number of Calendar objects.  Am I using them correctly?

My code snipet is:

```
    Calendar TimeArrival = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar TimeDeparture = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeArrival.set  (2020,8,20,00,01);
    TimeDeparture.set(2020,8,20,20,30);
```

Comment: Given the fact that you only have the different overoads of `Calendar.getInstance(...)` to create a new calendar, and none of them allow you to set a date, I do not see any other was to do was it asked of you. --- A remark: in Java, variable names should always start wit a lowercase letter.

Comment: Make sure you're setting the month correctly - it's [zero-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-int-int-), so we're currently in month 7 (if "8" is meant to be the current month).

Comment: "Is it a single point in time" Yes. It's basically a number of milliseconds since epoch, along with a time zone, in order to let you get and set the parts of the date and time with respect to that zone.

Comment: Sorry for you, it’s unfortunate that the use of the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` class is mandatory. Teachers who require that deserve to be sacked.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering how I should be using java Calendar objects

Do not use the outdated error-prone date/time API from `java.util` package. Use the [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from `java.time` package. Learn more about it from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

An example:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime dateTimeArrival = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 8, 20, 00, 01);
        LocalDateTime dateTimeDeparture = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 8, 20, 20, 30);
        System.out.println(dateTimeArrival);
        System.out.println(dateTimeDeparture);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-20T00:01
2020-08-20T20:30
```

If you want to store timezone information, use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`. Choose the class as per your requirement from the [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) given below:

[image]

> I need to represent arrival and departure times for several train
> stations. Should I use a separate Calendar object for each arrival
> time and departure time separately? Can I include both in the same
> object?

If you have just a few instances of date-time information, use different variables as mentioned above. If you have several instances to store, you can use `List` (or array if you know the number of instances beforehand) e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LocalDateTime> dateTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        dateTimes.add(LocalDateTime.now());
        dateTimes.add(LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(2));
        dateTimes.add(LocalDateTime.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()));
        dateTimes.add(LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 10).atStartOfDay());
        // etc.

        System.out.println(dateTimes);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2020-08-14T21:37:14.427085, 2020-08-14T23:37:14.429504, 2020-08-31T21:37:14.429518, 2020-08-10T00:00]
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that storing your dates and times in objects of the modern `java.time` classes is not an option; use of the poorly designed and long-outdated `Calendar` class is mandatory. The modern `ZonedDateTime` would probably have been the best choice.

> … Should I use a separate Calendar object for each arrival time and
> departure time separately? Can I include both in the same object?

Yes, you need separate objects for arrival and departure time when you need to keep track of both. No, a `Calendar` object can hold only one time, so both won’t fit.

As a supplement allow me to show two other ways of initializing your `Calendar` objects.

**Modern: Use `java.time` anyway!**

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo");
    ZonedDateTime arrivalZdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 8, 20, 0, 1, 0, 0, zone);
    Calendar timeArrival = GregorianCalendar.from(arrivalZdt);
```

With this code, you are well prepared for the day when your teacher realizes that using `Calendar` was a very foolish idea, or you get another teacher.

**Old-fashioned: Use the GregorianCalendar constructor**

```
    Calendar timeArrival = new GregorianCalendar(2020, Calendar.AUGUST, 20, 0, 1);
```

Under no circumstances prefix your numbers with zeroes. Coincidentally `00` and `01` work for a time of `0:01`, but when you get around to `08` or `09`, your code will no longer compile. In Java (and many other languages) numbers that begin with `0` are taken to be octal numbers.

Comment: `With this code you are well prepared for the day when your teacher realizes that using Calendar was a very foolish idea, or you get another teacher.` - Well said!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question: What are you generating?

Computers represent time as a `long` number of milliseconds past 00:00:00 Jan 1, 1970 UTC. Your Calendar may also include a copy of the local time zone.

Finally, the call to Calendar.getInstance is likely to return a GregorianCalendar object.